# Convert Java to XML using xstream

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, xstream

I have started using the xstream library to convert from Java code to XML. My model java class is simple and given below:

```
class Person {
    String firstname;
    String lastname;    
    String age;
    public Person(String first, String last,String age) {
        firstname = first;
        lastname = last;
        this.age =  age;
    }
}
```

So using simple xstream API I am getting the output of the `toXML` method as below:

```
<Person>
  <firstname>David</firstname>
  <lastname>Goswami</lastname>
  <age>34</age>
</Person>
```

However, I want to tweak the output and get the string age as an attribute of the field firstname. In essence, I am expecting the xml output as below:

```
<Person>
  <firstname age="34">David</firstname>
  <lastname>Goswami</lastname>
 </Person>
```

Any help on how to do this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: JAXB is better for this IMHO. Also, I don't think you're going to be able to get age as an attribute of firstname rather than Person.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the documentation here, it shows a excelent example for what you are trying to achieve: 
With annotations http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html#Attributes or without http://xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html#attributes

Comment: You aren't 'converting from Java code to XML'. You are converting Java *objects* to XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`XStream.useAttributeFor()`](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#useAttributeFor%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) to declare a property to be serialized as an attribute:

```
xstream.useAttributeFor(Person.class, "age");
```

Comment: If we have String, will it add attribute to all strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
@XStreamAsAttribute
String age;
```

Comment: This will add the age attribute to the Person element.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I have already tried these options. They would make the output like this --

Comment: <Person age="34">
  <firstname>David</firstname>
  <lastname>Goswami</lastname>
</Person>However, I want age as an attribute for firstname. Like this

Comment: I wanted to have the xml like in my question, with age as an attribute with firstname.

Comment: Exactly Buhb, I want age as an attribute of firstname.

Comment: @user496934: why do you want age as an attribute to firstname? That doesn't make any sense, semantically.

Comment: You are right it is attribute of Person class rather than firstname field. Lets investigate it again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use user-defined Converter, good example with the similar problem is there:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/426981/XML/XStream-variable-as-attribute-another